How do I get Google authentication with offline /ServerAuth Code (Mac+Webapp) working?
I am trying to use google-sign-in on my Mac with the serverAuthCode. I have set up two Oauth Client IDs (iOS for Mac app and Web for the service that would run on localhost)
I am able to sign-in and get the serverAuthCode successfully. However, when I try to get the credentials on my python, I can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing??
Here is the code
@app.route('/auth', methods=['POST'])                                              
def authenticate():                                                                
    auth_code = request.form.get('auth_code')                                      
    required_scopes = request.form.get('scopes')                                   
                                                                                   
    # If this request does not have `X-Requested-With` header, this could be a CSRF
    if not request.headers.get('X-Requested-With'):                                
        abort(403)                                                                 
                                                                                   
    try:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        print("Inside authenticate")                                               
        print(auth_code)                                                           
         # Split the scopes by comma and trim any whitespace                       
        scopes = [scope.strip() for scope in required_scopes.split(',')] if required_scopes else []
                                                                                   
        print(f"Scopes: {scopes}")                                                 
                                                                                   
        print("Getting credentials")                                               
        credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(              
            CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,                                                    
            scopes,                                                                
            auth_code                                                              
        )                                                                          
        print("Got credentials!")                                                  
                                                                                                
                                                                                   
    except client.FlowExchangeError as e:                                          
        print("Client FlowExchangeError!")                                         
        print(e)                                                                   
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 400    

I get a FlowExchangeError when I run this. See below
Scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts']
Getting credentials
Client FlowExchangeError!
redirect_uri_mismatchBad Request
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2024 13:03:08] "POST /auth HTTP/1.1" 400
This is with credentials.json as is (with redirect_uri) to localhost. If I unset the redirect_uri and use the credentials, I get oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: Missing property "redirect_uris" in a client type of "web". A couple of questions

Is this flow still supported? Looks like library has been deprecated, and this documentation is old https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access
Does redirect_uri even need to be set, I don't have a web app
What's the right way to get this working?

See above, I have already mentioned everything!
